# Why am i getting a attribute error when its in the right format?

Tags: python, colors

I keep getting a issue where color bassed commands arent working. I have tried variables and (_color) in front of the 'color'. I have never ran into this problem befor.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(400,400)

ray = turtle.Turtle
ray.pencolor('red')
ray.dot(20)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mu_code/words(1).py", line 7, in <module>
    ray.pencolor('red')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 2257, in pencolor
    return self._color(self._pencolor)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_color'
```

Comment: where exactly is the Stacktrace that gives you this error? And where is the exact code to reproduce the error? _This_ ain't it. [edit] your post and add the full stacktrace and the [mre]  to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the parentheses, because of which instead of object of `Turtle` class, `ray` is being misassigned.

```
>>> import turtle
>>> ray = turtle.Turtle
>>> type(ray)
<class 'type'>
>>> ray = turtle.Turtle()
>>> type(ray)
<class 'turtle.Turtle'>
```

Edit the below line in your code.

```
ray = turtle.Turtle()
```

will work.